# Как стилизовать отдельные буквы в HAML?

Tags: html, haml

Если стилизация полного слова это, примерно, так:

```
%h5{ style: "color: #fff;" }TEXT
```

то как, допустим, добавить разные цвета разным буквам?

По аналогии с:

```
<h5>
  <font style="color: #fff">T</font><font style="color: #3452be">E</font>XT
</h5>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для отмены переноса инлайн-элемента на новую строку следуем использовать `>` :

```
%h5
  %font{ style: "color: #fff;" }>T
  %font{ style: "color: #3452be;" }>E
  XT
```

Comment: Между буквами появляется пробел.

Comment: @lif3ar дополнил ответ